# extrating xml node values from xml string assinging to variable using select into in oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

my web application passes data as xml string to stored procedure in Oracle.
following is the string:

```
"  <DETAIL>
  <LON_tInstEnt>
    <DBrID />
    <BrID>124</BrID>
    <DPrdID />
    <PrdID>217</PrdID>
    <DAcctID />
    <AcctID>124217000002</AcctID>
    <AlterAcctID />
    <BrID_FK />
    <PrdID_FK />
    <CusID_FK>979125</CusID_FK>
    <OprBrID>124</OprBrID>
    <TenureYears>0</TenureYears>
    <Title />
    <Initial />
    <MemFName />
    <MemMName />
    <ProcessingDt>04-05-2017</ProcessingDt>
    <DCusBrID />
    <CusBrID>124</CusBrID>
    <DCusID />
    <CusID>702010</CusID>
    <MemLName>Mr. ABHIMANYU SAHOO</MemLName>
    <AcctLevelAdd>N</AcctLevelAdd>
    <PurpofLn />
    <DAppRegNo />
    <AppRegNo />
    <DSectorCode />
    <SectorCode />
    <AppliedAmt>10000</AppliedAmt>
    <TotEligibleAmt>10000</TotEligibleAmt>
    <SANCTIONAMT>10000</SANCTIONAMT>
    <LnAmt>0</LnAmt>
    <SanctionDt>04-05-2017</SanctionDt>
    <OpeningDt />
    <TenureMonths>84</TenureMonths>
    <TenureDays>0</TenureDays>
    <EXPIRYDT>27-05-2017</EXPIRYDT>
    <ValueDt>04-05-2017</ValueDt>
    <DEmpDgnCd />
    <EmpDgnCd />
    <DSanctionBy />
    <SanctionBy>393</SanctionBy>
    <SanctnAuth>BO</SanctnAuth>
    <LSONO />
    <CyID>INR</CyID>
    <SplRateID />
    <IntVariance>LT</IntVariance>
    <IntVarRate>0</IntVarRate>
    <MoratoriumMonth>0</MoratoriumMonth>
    <BalanceDays>0</BalanceDays>
    <RepayStDt />
    <Remarks />
    <ttsfplintamt />
    <TTSFSFDDT />
    <CBOFSARFAESIINITD />
    <TTDAOFNOTICEISSEDT />
    <TTDAOFPOSSIONDT />
    <TTDAOFSALEDT />
    <ttsfVALOFPROPERTY />
    <CBOFMULFINANCE />
    <CBOFRAUD />
    <APPROVE>N</APPROVE>
    <SENDTOEDIT>Y</SENDTOEDIT>
    <CRTDBY>rakesh729</CRTDBY>
    <CRTDDT>27-05-2017  01:47:38.8381250</CRTDDT>
    </LON_tInstEnt>
    <TBLCONTROL>
    <DefaulterList />
    <AddressHdn><NewDataSet> 
    <Table ID="702010" ADDTYPE="1" ADDRESS="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" PLACE="ROUREKELA" 
    CITY="SUNDARGARH" STATE="ORISSA" PLACECODE="769001" PHONE1="1234567890" 
    PHONE2="1234567890" EMAIL="AXG@MAIL.COM" MOBILE="8895939630" PAGER="" WEB="" 
    STREET="SECTOR-21" COUNTRY="INDIA" PURPOSE="CUS" STATUS="" /></NewDataSet>
    </AddressHdn>
    <AcctCharge />
    <HdnRepaySch />
    <IntParam>
    <NewDataSet>  <ITEMDET>    
    <IntRateType>FX</IntRateType>    
    <IRTAllowOverride>0</IRTAllowOverride>    
    <IntCalcType>SMP</IntCalcType>    
    <ICTAllowOverride>0</ICTAllowOverride>    
    <IntCompFreq />    <CompFreqType />    
    <ICmpFAllowOverride>0</ICmpFAllowOverride>    
    <ICmpFTAllowOverride>0</ICmpFTAllowOverride>    
    <IntCalcFreq>ONFREQ</IntCalcFreq>    
    <CalcFreqType>FIN</CalcFreqType>    
    <ICFAllowOverride>0</ICFAllowOverride>    
    <ICFTAllowOverride>0</ICFTAllowOverride>    
    <ProdDaysCalcType>DLY</ProdDaysCalcType>    
    <PDCTAllowOverride>0</PDCTAllowOverride>
    <IntRepayFreq>MLY</IntRepayFreq>    
    <RepayFreqType>FIN</RepayFreqType>    
    <IRFAllowOverride>0</IRFAllowOverride>    
    <IRFTAllowOverride>0</IRFTAllowOverride>    
    <IntRepayType>EFI</IntRepayType>    
    <IRepTAllowOverride>0</IRepTAllowOverride>    
    <IntCapitalizeFreq>MLY</IntCapitalizeFreq>    
    <CapitalizeFreqType>FIN</CapitalizeFreqType>    
    <ICapFAllowOverride>0</ICapFAllowOverride>    
    <ICapFTAllowOverride>0</ICapFTAllowOverride>    
    <IntAccrualFreq>MLY</IntAccrualFreq>    
    <AccrualFreqType>FIN</AccrualFreqType>    
    <IAFAllowOverride>0</IAFAllowOverride>    
    <IAFTAllowOverride>0</IAFTAllowOverride>    
    <IntDemandFreq>NA</IntDemandFreq>    
    <DemandFreqType>FIN</DemandFreqType>    
    <IDFAllowOverride>0</IDFAllowOverride>    
    <IDFTAllowOverride>0</IDFTAllowOverride>    
    <IntProdDays>365</IntProdDays>  
    </ITEMDET></NewDataSet></IntParam>
    <BusnsDate>04-05-2017</BusnsDate>
    <ROI><NewDataSet>  
    <ITEMDET EffDate="01-10-2011" DurSlab="NA" AmtSlab="0.0000 TO 50000.0000 " 
     PercSlab="NA" GROSSROI="10.00" NETROI="10.00" />
    </NewDataSet></ROI>
    <IntVarTmp />
    <IntVarTemp />
    <RepayTemp />
    <MnuID />
    <ScrMVal />
    <AddressRdOnly>Y</AddressRdOnly>
    <GroupID />
    <InterestParameter />
    <InterestRate />
    <RepaymentCalc />
    <InstallmentAmount>166</InstallmentAmount>
    <FirstMonInst />
    <RestMonthInst />
    <RepaymentSch />
    <DODeedDt />
    <DOCDt />
    <DOMDt />
    <EcumFrmDt />
    <EcumToDt />
    <FurEcumFrmDt />
    <FurEcumToDt />
    <Pincode />
    <DocType />
    <SubReg />
    <DocNum>0</DocNum>
    <MortBy>BO</MortBy>
    <District />
    <Taluka />
    <SecId />
    <PropId />
    <SecVal />
    </TBLCONTROL>
    <CUS_tCusMst>
    <MemFatHusFName />
    <MemFatHusMName />
    <MemId>702010</MemId>
    <SurType />
    <MemFatHusLName />
    <DOB>09-04-1971</DOB>
    <WhetherRepatriate>N</WhetherRepatriate>
    </CUS_tCusMst>
    <TBLCONTROLDEF>
    <HDU_PK_ID />
    <URL />
    <DynTlBrChange />
    <DisableAll />
    </TBLCONTROLDEF>
    <LON_tAcctCharges>
    <ChargeID />
    <LSTAPPRVDBY />
    <LSTAPPRVDDT />
    <APPROVE>N</APPROVE>
    <REJECT />
    <SENDTOEDIT>Y</SENDTOEDIT>
    <CRTDBY>rakesh729</CRTDBY>
    <CRTDDT>27-05-2017  01:47:38.8381250</CRTDDT>
    </LON_tAcctCharges>
    </DETAIL>"
```

in the stored procedure I store the xml string into a table called AccountData.
insert into accountData()

AccountData table has only one field named as "data".
create table accountdata (data clob);

now i need to read xml string and store the values into two variables
(v_SanctionAmount, v_CrtdBy) using SELECT INTO query.
The query i am using is given below.

```
SELECT cols.SanctionAmt,cols.CrtdBy
INTO v_SanctionAmount,v_CrtdBy
FROM accountData
cross join XMLTABLE('/DETAIL/LON_tInstEnt'
passing xmltype(data)
COLUMNS sanctionAmt NUMBER(19,4),
        crtdby      VARCHAR2(25)) cols;`
```

When I run the above query i get ORA-00905: missing keyword.
How to read xml node and store it into variables using SELECT INTO query

Advance Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of syntax error .  Try this:

```
SELECT
    cols.*
INTO v_SanctionAmount,v_CrtdBy
FROM
    accountdata,
    XMLTABLE ( '/DETAIL/LON_tInstEnt'
        PASSING accountdata.data COLUMNS
            "sanctionAmt" NUMBER(19,4) PATH 'SANCTIONAMT',
            "crtdby" VARCHAR2(25) PATH 'CRTDBY'
    ) cols
```

And take some time to read the documentation - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm